# Polymorphic React component has incorrect type inferences in IDE

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

```js
declare const MyComponent = <A extends {id: bigint|number}>(props: MyProps<A>) => React.FC<{}>

interface MyProps<A extends {id: number}> {
  data: A[]
  orderBy: keyof A
}

declare const x: { id: number, foo: string }[]

const Foo = () => {
  <MyComponent data={x} orderBy="foo"/> // <-- Type 'keyof A' is not assignable to type 'never'
}
```

I think this is because TS is failing to infer from `data` that type is of type `{ id: number, ... }` so thus it thinks `data` is of type `{}` and thus `keyof A` is of type `never` (and so `orderBy` cannot be anything at all).

So my question is how can I fix this other than `// @ts-ignore` right above? Can I manually specify the type of `A` somehow in my TSX? I can't do anything like

```js
import { MyComponent } from ...
declare const specify = <A>() => typeof MyComponent<A> // <-- error here because of the <A> part after MyComponent

const Foo = <A ...>() => {
  const SpecialMyComponent = specify<A>()
  return <SpecialMyComponent .../>
}
```

It seems you can't do those generics inside your TSX without TS thinking it's TSX instead of specifying the value of a generic.

Answer (score 0):

I've provided explanatory comments in the code below. Feel free to reply if something's not clear:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAKC4Hpe4AI2ABzYADt4Ad0JwQwAgQkja9RjAAWCuFnHAI4uBLgBZAJ4AFemAIAuLjDNgUcAJIAROAF5EXOEaRbIVEJeAAfOHEsEEEUKG4qbgcnF3MrCBs4AB4AQTgUAA8YFHEkIg8APm9ffyQMGAwgnIBtAF1uf2hUKAAhMyCAaxQzCDQ4HISk-jgAZSwRERQCGH1xIKwCF1IKGAA6bcoAURwUEBL4YDGRrBYXVlK45TgAKRmADThoOAw4cgZIcTnOCaepwJAQJb2VDkHAYVi0XSUVamMwAYX+BiBuXyRRKZTc7gqAAowNY7Cj0jZchUAJRBA57BnHU7nJLQ2Hwv7iZZwApBBABIJRGJxDi0CAQILLKDKMVUNpJLk8gBiEuqRJp3iqCD82XM6PAmMkYPqGC8CAKNC6cT6XgARGgJXbeFVphABlwqDw+AIcqUADS0CQYHA4My7CNwMxLQPXOConIAOR0mzgi0BMvIRCkwE0cAAKu8AIQ8RzOOAATWqAuAgWCYkkYsEGAAXlKYDLxCIFXBElx2XCXEr4P1KwqeMO4D04erNV5tbqsvqMYDJFkK1U6g1zWYrVBura7c2W3a4C6zwJ3Z7uEA)

```ts
import {default as React} from 'react';

// bigint was missing from this union in MyProps:
type ID = {
  id: bigint | number;
};

type MyProps <A extends ID> = {
  data: A[];
  orderBy: keyof A;
};

// Suggestion: use React.ReactElement if you're rendering JSX or a component that does:
declare function MyComponent <A extends ID>(props: MyProps<A>): React.ReactElement;

declare const x: { id: number; foo: string; }[];

const Foo = () => {
  <MyComponent data={x} orderBy="foo"/> // ok
}


// And, finally... yes, you CAN use generics with TSX!

type Y = { id: bigint; baz: string[]; };
declare const y: Y[];

const Bar = () => {
  <MyComponent<Y> data={y} orderBy="baz" /> // ok
};
```